# Extracting parameter types in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I write a function in Julia that takes a `Dict{K,V}` as an argument, then creates arrays of type `Array{K,1}` and `Array{V,1}`. How can I extract the types `K` and `V` from the Dict object so that I can use them to create the arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sven and John's answers are both quite right. If you don't want to introduce method type parameters the way John's code does, you can use the `eltype` function:

```
julia> d = ["foo"=>1, "bar"=>2]
["foo"=>1,"bar"=>2]

julia> eltype(d)
(ASCIIString,Int64)

julia> eltype(d)[1]
ASCIIString (constructor with 1 method)

julia> eltype(d)[2]
Int64

julia> eltype(keys(d))
ASCIIString (constructor with 1 method)

julia> eltype(values(d))
Int64
```

As you can see, there are a few ways to skin this cat, but I think that `eltype(keys(d))` and `eltype(values(d))` are by far the clearest and since the `keys` and `values` functions just return immutable view objects, the compiler is clever enough that this doesn't actually create any objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I decided to accept this answer because it was the most general (will also work on other iterable data structures).

Comment: `eltype(d)` now returns `Pair{ASCIIString,Int64}` and `eltype(d)[1]` no longer works. (Julia v0.4)

Comment: `keytype` and `valtype` are built-ins as of v0.4, and take the place of `eltype(d)[1]` and `eltype(d)[2]`, respectively.

Comment: Noting that as of v0.6, `eltype(d)[1]` no longer works, at least for dictionaries. I get the error: `MethodError: Cannot \`convert\` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Pair{String,Int64}`, and the thing returned from `eltype()` is a `Pair{String,Int}`. That said, `eltype(keys(d))` still works as expected

Answer (score 8):

If you're writing a function that will do this for you, you can make the types a parameter of the function, which may save you some run-time lookups:

```
julia> function foo{K, V}(d::Dict{K, V}, n::Integer = 0)
          keyarray = Array(K, n)
          valarray = Array(V, n)
          # MAGIC HAPPENS
          return keyarray, valarray
       end
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> x, y = foo(["a" => 2, "b" => 3])
([],[])

julia> typeof(x)
Array{ASCIIString,1}

julia> typeof(y)
Array{Int64,1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keys` and `values` in combination with `typeof`:

```
# an example Dict{K, V}
d = Dict{Int64, ASCIIString}()

# K
typeof(keys(d))
Array{Int64,1}

# V
typeof(values(d))
Array{ASCIIString,1}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `keys` and `values` now return iterators, not arrays. You need to add in a call to `collect` in newer versions of Julia to get an array out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in the types, you can use `eltype(d)`, or define even more specific functions

```
keytype{K}(d::Dict{K}) = K
valuetype{K,V}(d::Dict{K,V}) = V
```

and find the type immediately through

```
keytype(d)
valuetype(d)
```

As far as I understand, this should be pretty efficient because the compiler can deduce most of this at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

For iterables, the `eltype` approach that is already given in other answers works well enough. E.g.

```
julia> d = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2

julia> K, V = eltype(keys(d)), eltype(values(d))
(Symbol, Int64)

julia> K
Symbol

julia> V
Int64
```

This approach is generalisable to all *iterables*. However I would like to offer another approach which will generalise to other kinds of object (and still doesn't use the method type signature approach):

```
julia> d = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2

julia> typeof(d)
Dict{Symbol, Int64}

julia> K, V = typeof(d).parameters
svec(Symbol, Int64)

julia> K
Symbol

julia> V
Int64
```

You can see that the `Dict{Symbol, Int64}` type has a field `parameters` which you can unpack to obtain the type parameters. This works on `struct`s too:

```
julia> struct MyStruct{S, T}
           a::S
           b::T
       end

julia> x = MyStruct(1, 1.0)
MyStruct{Int64, Float64}(1, 1.0)

julia> S, T = typeof(x).parameters
svec(Int64, Float64)

julia> S
Int64

julia> T
Float64
```