# Julia multiple dispatch not matching subtypes

Tags: julia

Can someone help me understand why this julia function definition isn't matched by my attempt to use it seen below?

My naive assumption is that the `Array{ASCIIString,1}` that is being passed into the function should match the function definition of `Array{AbstractString,1}`, and so on.

```
julia> function test(a::Array{AbstractString,1}, b::AbstractString, c::Any) end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test([""],"","")
ERROR: MethodError: `test` has no method matching test(::Array{ASCIIString,1}, ::ASCIIString, ::ASCIIString)
Closest candidates are:
  test(::Array{AbstractString,1}, ::AbstractString, ::Any)

julia>
```

Comment: The reason is that Julia types are *invariant* which means `issubtype(Array{ASCIIString,1},Array{AbstractString,1})` is false. Look at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#man-parametric-types for more information.

Comment: This is a simpler example of the problem in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688923/julia-parametric-function-for-array-of-array-with-multiple-dispatch). However, the presentation of the issue is different enough that I vote we leave it open. For quick reference, the syntax you need is `function test{T<:AbstractString}(a::Array{T}, b::T, c::Any)`, although you might want a second type parameter if you want to allow the element type of `a` to be different to the type of `b`...

Comment: Oops, ignore my nonsense about "second type parameter" in previous comment. If you want to let element type of `a` and type of `b` differ, then `function test{T<:AbstractString}(a::Array{T}, b::AbstractString, c::Any)` is sufficient. The key point is that `ASCIIString <: AbstractString` is `true`, but `Array{ASCIIString, 1} <: Array{AbstractString, 1}` is `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is worthwhile turning my two comments above into an answer.

As @DanGetz indicated, the important phrase here is *invariant*. In this particular case, this principle implies that `ASCIIString <: AbstractString` evaluates to `true`, but `Array{ASCIIString, 1} <: Array{AbstractString, 1}` evaluates to `false`. So for the function defined as in your question to work, you would need to pass in an array `a` with `eltype(a)` evaluating to `AbstractString`. Passing in `a` with `eltype(a)` evaluating to `ASCIIString` doesn't work, because this is not a subtype of `Array{AbstractString, 1}`.

To solve your problem, you need type parameters. If you want to only define the function for the case where the type of `b` matches `eltype(a)`, then you would use:

```
function test{T<:AbstractString}(a::Array{T}, b::T, c::Any)
```

If you want to allow the type of `b` to differ from `eltype(a)`, but enforce `b` to be a subtype of `AbstractString`, you would use:

```
function test{T<:AbstractString}(a::Array{T}, b::AbstractString, c::Any)
```

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you! And for others who are following this question, a few things I had to look up: `eltype(...)` returns the type of a collection, for example: `eltype(Array{ASCIIString, 1}) # Returns: ASCIIString`.  Also, I found this article related and a helpful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991220/extracting-parameter-types-in-julia

Comment: @DavidParks Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Since Colin's answer, the syntax of Julia changed. Since Julia version 1, it looks like this:

```
function test(a::Array{T}, b::T, c::Any) where {T<:AbstractString}
```

See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Methods-1